# basis for equal row sum vector space

Tags: vector-spaces

Consider the vector space containing n $\times$ n matrices such that for every row in the matrix the sum of the elements is the same. What is a basis for this vector space ? (Since the entries of the matrix are from a field we could also consider without loss of generality the sum of the elements of every row is 1. )

Comment: What do you do with the null matrix, then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is defined by $n-1$ linear equations:
$$\sum_{j=1}^n a_{1j}=\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}\qquad(i=2,\dots,n),$$
and these linear equations are obviously linearly independent, so the codimension of this vector spave, $V$, is $n-1$. So
$$\dim V=n^2-n+1.$$

Answer (score 0):

The $n$ constant row sums
$$
A c = c \\
c^T = (1, \dotsc, 1) \\
A^T = (a_1,\dotsc,a_n)
$$
determine $n$ equations 
$$
c \cdot a_k = 1
$$ 
in $\mathbb{F}^n$.
We linearize the $n^2$ unknowns $a_{ij}$ into a single vector $a \in\mathbb{F}^{n^2}$ with
$$
a^T = (a_1^T,\dotsc,a_n^T)
$$
and get the $n$ equations
$$
c_k \cdot a = 1 \\
c_k^T = (0_n^T, \dotsc, 0_n^T, \underbrace{c^T}_{k-\text{th}}, 0_n^T, \dotsc, 0_n^T) \\
0_n^T = (\underbrace{0, \dotsc, 0}_{n \times})
$$
which form the inhomogeneous system
$$
B a = c \quad (*) \\
B^T = (c_1, \dotsc, c_n)
$$
where $B \in \mathbb{F}^{n\times n^2}$ is in row echelon form with rank $n$.

The solution space $S$ of $(*)$ is not linear, $0 \not\in S$, but affine.
It is of dimension $n^2 - n$.

**Example:**

Let us consider the case $n=2$. Then $(*)$ turns into
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
a_1 \\
a_2 \\
a_3 \\
a_4
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
1
\end{pmatrix}
\quad (**)
$$
A particular solution of the inhomogeneous system $(**)$ is
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
1 \\
0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Linear independent solutions of the homogeneous system $B a = 0$ are
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
1 \\
-1 \\
0 \\
0
\end{array}
\right)
\quad
\text{and}
\quad
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
0 \\
0 \\
1 \\
-1 
\end{array}
\right)
$$
So the solution is
$$
a =
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
1 \\
0
\end{pmatrix}
+
\alpha_1
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
1 \\
-1 \\
0 \\
0
\end{array}
\right)
+ \alpha_2
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
0 \\
0 \\
1 \\
-1 
\end{array}
\right)
\quad (\alpha_1, \alpha_2 \in \mathbb{F})
$$
Interpreted as matrices we get
$$
A =
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
+
\alpha_1
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
1 & -1 \\
0 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
+ \alpha_2
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
0 & 0 \\
1 & -1 
\end{array}
\right)
\quad (\alpha_1, \alpha_2 \in \mathbb{F})
$$

**Example:**

For $n=3$ we end up with
$$
A =
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
+
\alpha_1
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
1 & -1 & 0 \\
0 &  0 & 0 \\
0 &  0 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
+ \alpha_2
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
0 &  0 & 0 \\
1 & -1 & 0 \\
0 &  0 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
+ \alpha_3
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
0 &  0 & 0 \\
0 &  0 & 0 \\
1 & -1 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
+ \\
\alpha_4
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
1 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 0 &  0 \\
0 & 0 &  0
\end{array}
\right)
+ \alpha_5
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
0 & 0 &  0 \\
1 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 0 &  0
\end{array}
\right)
+ \alpha_6
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
0 & 0 &  0 \\
0 & 0 &  0 \\
1 & 0 & -1
\end{array}
\right)
\quad (\alpha_1, \dotsc, \alpha_6 \in \mathbb{F})
$$

**Solution:**

The particular solution generalizes to a matrix with the first column having all $1$ elements, and the other columns are zero.

For the homogeneous solutions we have $n$ rows and place the $1$ at the first columns, then we have $n-1$ columns left to place the $-1$, giving $n(n-1) = n^2 - n$ possibilities. (This is more a guess than a proof).